# jQuery Mobile - Collapsible not collapsing/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So I am trying to create a menu that can be triggered by clicking on a link.
The only problem is a submenu in my menu isn't collapsing.
It won't even show the menu item.

I created a jsFiddle to show my problem and I don't know what is happening.
the "data-role='collapsible'" doesn't seem to be working at all.

jsFiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/de3cb7br/)`

```
<div data-role="page" id="wrapper" data-url="wrapper" class="ui-content">
    <div role="header">
        <a href="#menu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-a ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon="delete">Home</li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Skills</li>
                    <li data-role="collapsible">Hello
                        <ul>
                            <li>Beautiful</li>
                            <li>World</li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>
                    <li>About</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The menu item with "Hello" doesn't show at all and the subitems won't collapse. What am I doing wrong or what is causing this to fail?

Comment: According to [docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html), header of collapsible element should be in `<hX></hX>`. So I wrap _Hello_ with `<h3></h3>` and it works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de3cb7br/6/).

Comment: oh wow ... that's it? :p well, thank you! :D in a way it's kinda stupid that it doesn't work because of one simple <hx></hX> tag. Anyhow, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it's not stupid - just rules of jQuery Mobile to determine what is what. Since all solved questions in SO should have accepted answer, either you can delete the question or I can post my comment as an answer, if you are ready to accept it. Or you can improve your own answer so that it will be real answer for this question.

Comment: go ahead and post your comment as an answer ;) you deserve the credits for it, I'll accept it :)

Comment: While I was being offline, jegadees posted an answer with the same explanation. I doubt there is any sense to post the same answer, so you can just accept his answer.

Comment: @Regent I was going through this question and found that no answer was posted.So i decided to post an answer so that the question will be meaningful and useful for future reference.I will delete my answer so that you can post it,Apologies

Comment: @jaggs your answer is complete and correct one. Also you are the first who has posted it. I stay in comments, when there already are correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Jquery docs

> To create a collapsible block of content, create a container and add
>   the data-role="collapsible" attribute.Directly inside this container,
>   add any header (H1-H6) or legend element. The framework will style the
>   header to look like a clickable button and add a "+" icon to the left
>   to indicate it's expandable.

So in your case ,

```
<div data-role="page" id="wrapper" data-url="wrapper" class="ui-content">
    <div role="header">
        <a href="#menu" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-a ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon="delete">Home</li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Skills</li>
                    <li data-role="collapsible"><h2>Hello</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Beautiful</li>
                            <li>World</li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>
                    <li>About</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jegadeesb/de3cb7br/8/)